# Xpra Server HTML5- Start Menu Not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I have been working through this issue for a few weeks now, Basically I have set up an xpra server on Ubuntu 16.04 (And have tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and  RHEL 8.0.0  with the same results) and can get the server running an html5 output and view it successfully on my local machine.

But once I am viewing the local output, I cannot run any program from the "Start" menu in the system tray. The only issue I can figure out with regards to the bug tracking on the xpra site is that the xdg menu file appears to be missing. So when I run

```
python2 -c "from xdg.Menu import parse;parse()"
```

I get an error that:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 570, in parse
raise ParsingError ('File not found', "/etc/xdg/menus/%s" % candidate)

xdg.Exceptions.ParsingError: ParsingError in file '/etc/xdg/menus/debian-menu.menu', File not found
```

Which according to http://xpra.org/trac/ticket/2174?cversion=2&cnum_hist=4 is an error which sometimes occurs with XDG. I can't figure out how to fix this with any of the steps they outlined and am not even certain that this is whats causing the problem.

Below is a screencap of the system tray menu not opening as well. 
[image]

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest version from xpra.org, which includes the workarounds, in particular this one: http://xpra.org/trac/changeset/21880/xpra